# Prestashop Order Payment Processing - Missing bank wire details and customer phone

Tags: prestashop, payment-method, prestashop-modules

I want to use Prestashop HTTP API to allow a client to place and pay for an order.

Currently I can create an order using the Webservice API. For payment specifically, I send ps_wirepayment and Bank Wire.
The order is placed correctly in the store.

However, transfer details are not returned in the created order. Where is this information stored so that I can show that in my client app?

Secondly, for other payment methods that require phone number for example, where should that phone number be sent, since the customer and order fields dont seem to have that in their schema.

I tried creating an order, which works.

I was expecting to get the bank wire details after the order is placed or be able to fetch it from somewhere.

Furthermore, I expected a phone attribute somewhere for payment modules that use the client's phone number.

Answer (score 0):

You can find banktransfer info in your database in table "ps_configuration" :
BANK_WIRE_OWNER, BANK_WIRE_DETAILS and BANK_WIRE_ADDRESS. (do keep in mind these are only created once you actually set them with the module)

Phone numbers are stored in the address.